# .relationship(…, cascade="all") does not delete children when multiple parents "bulk" deleted using session.execute(delete(Parent))

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

I worte some code in Python for managing some database stuff.
All I want to do, is to delete all parents of a 1-to-many relationsship , which should automatically delete all children. Here is my example code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    single_parent = True
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')



engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


session = Session(engine)
# create data
parent1 = Parent(name='Parent 1', children=[Child(name='Child 1'), Child(name='Child 2')])
parent2 = Parent(name='Parent 2', children=[Child(name='Child 3'), Child(name='Child 4')])
session.add_all([parent1, parent2])
session.commit()

# Check
print("Before:")
print(session.query(Parent).all())
print(session.query(Child).all())

# Delete
session.query(Parent).delete()
session.commit()
```

When running, the parent elements will be deleted but none of the child elements.
What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The `cascade=` option on the `relationship()` does not apply when using `session.query(Parent).delete()`. It only applies when an individual instance of the object is deleted using `session.delete(object_instance)`. As noted in the [SQLALchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#delete): "Note that the ORM’s 'delete' and 'delete-orphan' behavior applies only to the use of the Session.delete() method to mark individual ORM instances for deletion within the unit of work process. It does not apply to “bulk” deletes, which would be emitted using the delete() construct"

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `parent_id` declaration:

Replace:

```
parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
```

With:

```
parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

However, it's not sufficient when you use `SQLite` as database because [*Foreign Key Constraints are not enabled by default*](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). <strike>You can enable Foreign Key Constraint with a `PRAGMA` directive at database level:</strike> (see @GordThompson's comment below)

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Or you can handle this feature with `SQLAlchemy by listening for events:

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlite3 import Connection as SQLite3Connection

# enable foreign keys. if you do not do this, ON DELETE CASCADE fails silently!
@listens_for(Engine, 'connect')
def _set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if isinstance(dbapi_connection, SQLite3Connection):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
        cursor.close()
```

Test:

```
# Check
print("Before:")
print(session.query(Parent).all())
print(session.query(Child).all())

# Delete only one parent
session.query(Parent).filter_by(name='Parent 2').delete()
session.commit()

# Check
print("After:")
print(session.query(Parent).all())
print(session.query(Child).all())
```

Output:

```
# I just modified the __repr__ of each table

Before:
[Parent(id=1, name='Parent 1'), Parent(id=2, name='Parent 2')]
[Child(id=1, name='Child 1', parent_name='Parent 1'), Child(id=2, name='Child 2', parent_name='Parent 1'), Child(id=3, name='Child 3', parent_name='Parent 2'), Child(id=4, name='Child 4', parent_name='Parent 2')]

After:
[Parent(id=1, name='Parent 1')]
[Child(id=1, name='Child 1', parent_name='Parent 1'), Child(id=2, name='Child 2', parent_name='Parent 1')]
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that (1) `ForeignKey(…, cascade="DELETE")` only affects DDL, so adding that will require that the table be re-created. (2) `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` does not store that value in the database, so the "connect" event listener is required.

Comment: @GordThompson 1) Thanks for clarifying this point, I obviously agree. 2) Why is there [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIbLy.jpg) in sqlitebrowser?

Comment: That setting in DB Browser for SQLite is unfortunately misleading. It makes "Foreign Keys" look like a database-specific setting, but it isn't. Try turning it off, clicking the "Save" button, closing the database, an then re-opening it.